# 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command from Maven

Tags: maven, svn, plugins, jenkins

When I do "Perform maven release" with dry-run on Jenkins, I get this error on console log:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.205s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Mar 13 10:29:44 ICT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/11M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Projects to build: [MavenProject: com.library:MYPROJECT:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ E:\jenkins\workspace\MYPROJECT\pom.xml]
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\jenkins\workspace\MYPROJECT\pom.xml to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/APGIS/modules/com.library$MYPROJECT/builds/2015-03-13_10-29-02/archive/com.library/MYPROJECT/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MYPROJECT-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) on project MYPROJECT: Unable to check for local  modifications
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I already installed SVN client with SlikSVN-1.6.1 and mvn-3.0.4 and checked the installed commands in command prompt of Maven-slave machine.

I tried to do "Perform maven release" with dry-run via command prompt on Maven-slave directly. The result is work!!.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Maven-release-plugin version in POM.xml is 2.4.0.

This problem is occurred in Windows7 of Maven-slave machine but WindowsXP isn't founded even thought the versions of SVN client and mvn between both machines are same.

What could be cause of this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you restart the slave?  Also, are you saying it works fine on Windows XP, but not on Windows 7?

Comment: I had restarted but the result is same. I have 2 slave machines. It uses WindowsXP and Windows7 respectively. This problem is founded in Windows7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Command output: 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This means the folder location of the *svn.exe* client executable is not in the **PATH** environment variable.

Comment: I already added and checked svn.exe client executable to the PATH environment of Slave machine. but it seem Jenkins cannot access to it. Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Use the Windows Start, Run menu option and type in cmd.exe. In the resulting command prompt window type in svn.exe and report the result of running that command.

Answer (score -1):

What OS is your slave? Jenkins runs under it's own user. If on Linux/Mac, it will run under `jenkins` user. Just cause you installed `svn` for your own user, doesn't mean it's accessible to all other users.

Login as jenkins, then verify:
`sudo su - jenkins`
`svn`

Comment: My slave uses Windows7 32bits.

Answer (score -1):

You could try enabling the `Tool locations` for the specific slave and explicitly specify the `HOME` of the `svn` installation.  To reach this, `Manage jenkins` -> `Manage nodes` -> `Your Windows 7 node` -> `Configure`